# How to go about starting a method chain in Object Oriented Programming?

Tags: oop

Imagine having two objects, A and B, and B is dependent on A. Now you need to first call a method on object A (let's say checkUpdates), and then call one on object B (relayInfo).

If OOP is your preferred approach is it best practice to
call A.checkUpdates() and then B.relayInfo() from B (or wherever)
OR call A.checkUpdates() which directly calls B.relayInfo() on a reference of B?

In short should you have these objects call methods on each other in a ping-pong-like manner, or should one of them (or a controller object) call methods sequentially for both of them?

Comment: That's much too vague. It's not even clear what you mean by "*B is dependent on A*". You'll get much better answers if you tag this question with a specific language and post some actual code (see also: [mcve]).

Comment: @melpomene thanks for your answer. I'll think about how to make it less vague. This is tricky because this question is about code design and not so much actual code. As soon as I post code I'm afraid I've already picked an approach, whereas the question is more about which way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the dependent object be responsible for this task

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B(new A());
        b.relayInfo();
    }
}

class A {
    void checkUpdates() {
        System.out.println("checkUpdates()");
    }
}

class B {
    final A a;

    B(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    void relayInfo() {
        if (a == null) {
            return;
        }
        a.checkUpdates();
        System.out.println("relayInfo()");
      }
}
```